# XCode ios 7 uitextfield type bar custome color

Tags: xcode, uitextfield

In a textField when you type some text, there is a bar or "pipe" `|` with blue color.
I want change this color to white, how can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `tintColor` of your `UITextField` like this:

`textField.tintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];`

Comment: Vote + thanks so much, in Main.storyboard i will see option Tin color in right menu tools, i will change to white color but don't work, now it working fine, thanks so much.